# Cannot pass parent component's object as prop in Vue after Laravel Mix update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-mix

I recently updated laravel mix in my project to the latest and immediately I was swarmed by Vue errors. I seem to struggle with this one especially. I have a component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ChildComponent :context="this"></ChildComponent>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import ChildComponent from './child-component';
    export default {
        components: { ChildComponent },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

This is the error I get: `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined"`.
Seems weird because in vue-devtools the parent component is present as an object in `context` prop of ChildComponent.
I should probably also add that context is defined as `context: {}` in ChildComponent's props.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not defined in the `<template>` and attempting to pass the entire `Vue` instance to the child seems like an anti-pattern. You should explicitly define and pass data and variables to children components, and (optionally) if you want to receive some data back from the child, you should emit events and bind to those events in the parent.

If you *must* access the parent component from the child, you can use `this.$parent` in the child component: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Parent-Component-Instance

But unless you have a good reason to reach for that `$parent` variable, it should be avoided as it tightly couples your components together.

Comment: Should I add that the components should be tightly couple together? Anyway thanks a lot, I know where to go on from here.

Comment: There's always exception to the rules, good luck with it all.